# subprocess.getstatusoutput('ls -l') only works on python shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, subprocess, importerror

Here I am trying to access the subprocess.getoutput()

module using the external program *(such as pyhello.py)* it shows the following error

```
>>>(status, output) = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)      
>>>AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getstatusoutput'
```

For this code (pyhello.py)

```
import subprocess 
def sub_pro(dir):
    cmd = 'ls -l' + dir
    (status, output) = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
    print(status,output)
```

But I can access using the python shell on the terminal it works fine

like this

Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 13 2018, 21:12:35)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.getstatusoutput('ls -l') 
drwxrwxr-x 6 name name 4096 Jul 14 11:37 somedirs 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 name name 1049 Jul 18 11:42 pyhello.py
```

Using

> 1.Python 3.5.5 on anaconda (64-bit)
>
> 2.Ubuntu LTS 16.04
>
> 3.Text editor Sublime 3

PS:
I also checked the following file on the anaconda dir

/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py

(It shows the subprocess.py contain getstatusoutput(cmd))

Comment: You are probably running python 2.  `getstatusoutput` is only in python 3.  Check your `$PATH` and `python -V`.

Comment: ~/Desktop/  python -V 
Python 3.5.5 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Comment: OK, then in your script that is failing put:  `import sys` then `print(sys.version)`.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks a lot man  (It shows  2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609])

Comment: What it's exactly happened here I didn't get it @cdarke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176218/discussion-between-vimal-raj-and-cdarke).